# Find rows that have one column value same but not the other

Tags: mysql

I have a table structure like this:

```
ProductId | Parentid | Name

1 | 1 | Abc

2 | 1 | Abc

3 | 2 | Xyz

4 | 3 | Xyz

5 | 3 | Abc
```

I need a query which finds such rows which have parentid as the same as the other rows but different name than the other.

For an example: Query should fetch below result, because parentid is same for both rows but name is not the same.

```
4 | 3 | Xyz

5 | 3 | Abc
```

Can somebody help forming the query?

Comment: Select distinct x.* from my_table x join my_table on some y thing is the same as some x thing and some other y thing is not the same as some other x thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is this:

```
SELECT ProductId, ParentId, Name
FROM mytable 
WHERE ParentId IN (
  SELECT Parentid
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY Parentid
  HAVING MIN(Name) <> MAX(Name))
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60338/3)

You can alternatively use `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT ProductId, m.ParentId, Name
FROM mytable m
INNER JOIN (SELECT Parentid
            FROM mytable
            GROUP BY Parentid
            HAVING MIN(Name) <> MAX(Name)) t
ON m.ParentId = t.ParentId
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60338/5)

As a final note, if you want *all* values in `Name` column to be distinct, then you have to use the following `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1  AND COUNT(DISTINCT Name) = COUNT(*)
```

Comment: Worked absolutely fine, couldn't thought of the min & max. Nice adaptation :)